# Improper removal of SQL Server cluster

Tags: sql-server, clustering

A node was evicted from a windows cluster without first uninstalling the sql first. When the node was put back, an error was produced when we tried to failover. It was reporting a missing dll. Feels like removing the node before uninstalling sql from it has corrupted or deleted part of the build.

Has anyone else encountered this situation? Can this be repaired or is it best to uninstall the sql from the node and start again installing a new sql node.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message in windows event log / Cluster logs and sql server error logs ? That will help to see exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: The error was "the node was added successfully but the sql server resource type could not be installed on it. Unable to find sqsrvres.dll on any of the cluster nodes" - this was the same error for sql server agent

Comment: was the node primary before being evicted?

Comment: This was passive at the time it was evicted

Answer (score 1):

I would first run a repair installation of your SQL Server installation on the node that was evicted.  This should at least get the appropriate binaries installed.  Then, run a [Discovery Report](http://sqlchad.com/?p=188) to validate what is and is not installed.  If your SQL node installation is no longer available, the reinstall the node.